# Deserialization of null string

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I'd like to deserialize XML document to a POCO object. But I'm receiving unexpected result. Actually I need to get on output `null` value for Country property, but it has value with `String.Empty`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ZIP xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ZIP>11111</ZIP>
  <CITY>111</CITY>
  <STATE>UT</STATE>
  <COUNTRY xs:Nil="true" />
</ZIP>
```

Properties looks like:

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
public string ZIP { get; set; }

[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
public string CITY { get; set; }

[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
public string STATE { get; set; }

[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
public string COUNTRY { get; set; }
```

I know that I can put some hooks with custom properties or implement `IXmlSerializable`, but it is just one from hundred of XML documents and POCO classes. Is there any generic solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now try it with the correct namespace; `xs` should here be an alias to `"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`, and it should be `xs:nil`, not `xs:Nil`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ZIP xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ZIP>11111</ZIP>
  <CITY>111</CITY>
  <STATE>UT</STATE>
  <COUNTRY xs:nil="true" />
</ZIP>
```

Comment: Actually I have just one little question. `[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]` - should I mark all of the nullable properties with this attribute or leave it as is?

Comment: @VolodymyrMelnychuk by *convention*, that alias is more commonly `"xsi"`, but it doesn't actually matter what the alias is called; it could be called `foo`

Comment: @VolodymyrMelnychuk you'll have to test it to see what works with/without that

Comment: FYI @MarcGravell it doesn't work without :) Thanks one more time for help.